# Input field value refill if empty after on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, textfield

So i'm working on a form. When you focus (click) the text field, the value becomes blank. Now i want the default value to re-appear if the user hasn't filled in anything.

So for instance i have a text field with ID Question1. This is what works for the clear on focus.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#Question1").val('Naam *');
   $("#Question1").focus(function() {
     $("#Question1").val('');
   });
  });
```

Any javascript code for that?

Edit: I can't use placeholders because of CMS restrictions (concrete5). The text fields are generated.

Comment: Why dont you use placeholders?

Comment: use placeholder ="something" , it will reappear if nothing written on it

Comment: http://google.com/?q=jquery+placeholder+plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this with the help of **[`blur()`](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)** event

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var temp = 'Naam *';
  $("#Question1").focus(function() {
    if (temp == this.value)
      // ------^-- empty the field only if the field value is initial  
      this.value = '';
      // emptying field value
  }).blur(function() {
    if (this.value.trim() == '')
      // -----^-- condition field value is empty
      this.value = temp;
      // if empty then updating with initial value
  }).val(temp);
  //----^-- setting initial value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Question1" />
```

Comment: This works, but once you type something in, and you click in the text field: the text field becomes blank + you can't delete what you filled in.

Comment: @JacobVanAchter : glad to help :)